# UPS API DotNetShipping isResidential not working as isResidential = true

Tags: c#, .net, ups

The below code snippets are working fine and sending the destination address to UPS API correctly.

But since I recently figured out the isResidential = true in UPS API doesn't do anything since the tag for Residential Addresses is ResidentialAddressIndicator = true.

How can I change the isResidential to ResidentialAddressIndicator. **I can't** modify the Address Class, since I'm using `using DotNetShipping` I need to find a way to send ResidentialAddressIndicator = true with the destination once the isResidential = true.

Is there a way to change it outside the class and attach it to destination? Any help would be appreciated.

Address class is like this:

```
public class Address
    {
        public Address(string city, string state, string postalCode, string countryCode) : this(null, null, null, city, state, postalCode, countryCode)
        {
        }

        public Address(string line1, string line2, string line3, string city, string state, string postalCode, string countryCode, bool isResidential = false)
        {
            Line1 = line1;
            Line2 = line2;
            Line3 = line3;
            City = city;
            State = state;
            PostalCode = postalCode;
            CountryCode = countryCode;
            IsResidential = isResidential;
        }

        public string City { get; set; }
        public string CountryCode { get; set; }
        public string CountryName { get; set; }
        public string Line1 { get; set; }
        public string Line2 { get; set; }
        public string Line3 { get; set; }
        public string PostalCode { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; }
        public bool IsResidential { get; set; }
}
```

And this is how I set destination address:

```
        var destination = new Address(
            "", 
            "", 
            order.SZipCode,
            order.SCountryShortName);

        destination.IsResidential = order.Residential; // bool value
        destination.State = "CA"
```

Comment: Are you not seeing this in the XML? https://github.com/kylewest/DotNetShipping/blob/master/DotNetShipping/ShippingProviders/UPSProvider.cs#L208

Comment: No I see IsResidential = true , I need to change it to ResidentialAddressIndicator = true.

Comment: maybe the reason is im using the old dotnetshipping.dll before they added the ResidentialAddressIndicator flag?

Comment: Doesn't seem very likely as it hasn't been updated for 2 years. You can always grab the source and build it yourself?

Comment: It worked,, seems like my DotNetShipping.dll was older than 2 years. I changed the file with the new one and it worked.